# Attempting to run Steam on a Chromebook and getting and error that says, “Steam may not run: libc.so.6”

Tags: linux, steam, steam-link

I am trying to run steam on myCchromebook, but I am having some difficulties with the process. I have successfully downloaded Steam with the Linux installer but when: Try to run it, it says the following:

> “You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6”

How do I download libc.so.6 and install it? Could anyone please help me with my situation. What should I do with the following message and what do I do to make everything work.

Comment: This particular Chromebook is x86 or ARM?